# Styling AutoCompleteTextView with AppCompat.EditText does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, material-design

I make material design style application

I want to change `AutoCompleteTextView` style
to style like in `android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText`

I added style to my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>
```

That works but the line colors does not change. 
[image]

EditTexts with material design seem to use `colorControlActivated` and `colorControlNormal`. Therefore, I have tried to override these properties in the previous style definition but it has no effect.
What I need to do, to make it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add the desired style to use for your widget in the xml this way :

```
<View
style="@style/NameOfYourTheme"
...
/>
```

If that doesn't work you could try to style it yourself.
You will have to change the TextView attributes which you can look up [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Textcolor for an instance could be changed by changing the `android:textColor` attribute which should be added to your style, for example :

```
<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>

<item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change the edittext line you have to change the background attribute, for example in this manner :

```
<item name ="android:background="@drawable/line_background"> </item>
```

And add a new file `line_background.xml` in your drawables folder with a similar content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">


    <stroke
        android:color="#c0c000"
        android:width="3dp"></stroke>
</shape>
```

Comment: textColor attribute works, but problem is that I can't change line colors (it's black on screen)

Comment: That just draws a line through the middle. It doesn't do a Material underline.

Comment: Thank you. What I had to do was to create a custom style similar to the one created above named `Autcomplete`, and assigned it as `android:theme="@style/Autocomplete"`

Answer (score 3):

I've created custom Tint Aware AutoCompleteTextView to solve this problem.

```
package com.atrinax.gist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class TintAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

private static final int[] TINT_ATTRS = {
        android.R.attr.background
};

public TintAutoComplete(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TintAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle);
}

public TintAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    TintTypedArray a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, attrs, TINT_ATTRS,
            defStyleAttr, 0);
    setBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(0));
    a.recycle();
}
}
```

Add this class to your project.
Use in xml like this:

```
<com.atrinax.gist.TintAutoComplete
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Downside of this solution is that it relies on internal class

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray
```

that might change or become unavailable in the future.
Please take a look at Derek's answer below - it is solving a problem with a background that arise from my answer.

Comment: This doesn't account for the dropdown background on v21 which becomes transparent. From my testing 4.4 and below defaults to the dark background.

Comment: I am aware of this issue, but I can't seem to find a workaround other that setting your own layout for list items or by changing view in adapter, like this, for example: `if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1).setBackgroundColor(backgroundLightColor);
        }`

Comment: I found a solution to this, see my answer for more info. Thanks for sharing this code snippet, very cool approach.

Comment: @DerekS I wish I could vote this up. Works perfectly, however I've tested it only on pre-Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 2):

To extrapolate on @Atrinax's answer, here's a class that will handle the `popupBackground` attribute by Extending AutoCompleteTextView and adding it to TINT_ATTRS

```
public class TintAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

private static final int[] TINT_ATTRS = {
        android.R.attr.background,
        android.R.attr.popupBackground
};

public TintAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TintAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle);
}

public TintAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    TintTypedArray a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(context, attrs, TINT_ATTRS,
            defStyleAttr, 0);
    setBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(0));
    setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(1));
    a.recycle();
}
}
```